# Filter and compare array_agg values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next query:

```
SELECT
     type,
     array_agg(DISTINCT food_name) as food,
     portion
FROM stored_meal
WHERE id = 23
AND event_timestamp >= '2020-09-01 19:49:38.634483'
AND event_timestamp < '2020-09-07 19:49:38.634483'
```

result of query is next:

```
type       food                portion
dinner     {cola, wine, pizza} 3 
launch     {cola, wine, pizza} 4
breakfast  {burger, pepsi}     5
```

I need to filter out rows which have the same 'food items' and 'lowest portion'
Expected result should be:

```
type       food                portion
launch     {cola, wine, pizza} 4
breakfast  {burger, pepsi}     5
```

I am new in SQL, so any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: The query doesn't use a `GROUP BY` so it should fail

Comment: Is this your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT type, food, portion
FROM (SELECT type, array_agg(DISTINCT food_name) as food, portion,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY array_agg(DISTINCT food_name) ORDER BY portion DESC) as seqnum
      FROM stored_meal
      WHERE id = 23 AND
           event_timestamp >= '2020-09-01 19:49:38.634483' AND
           event_timestamp < '2020-09-07 19:49:38.634483'
     ) sm
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```